# Transpose and create categorical values in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the below structure from which I am looking to transpose the variables into categorical. Intent is to find the weighted mix of the variables.

```
       data <- read.table(header=T, text='
              subject weight sex  test 
              1       2      M     control 
              2       3      F     cond1  
              3       2      F     cond2  
              4       4      M    control
              5       3      F    control
              6       2      F    control
               ')

      data
```

Expected output:

```
          subject weight control_F control_M cond1_F cond1_M cond2_F cond2_M
           1       2        0        1          0      0      0        0
           2       3        0        0          1      0      0        0
           3       2        0        0          0      0      1        0
           4       4        0        1          0      0      0        0
           5       3        1        0          0      0      0        0
           6       2        1        0          0      0      0        0
```

I tried using a combination of ifelse and cut, but just couldn't produce the output.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

TIA

Comment: `library(reshape2); dcast(data, subject+weight~sex+test, fun=length, drop=FALSE)` almost works

Comment: Another option would be `library(caret);dM <- dummyVars(subject+weight~ sex:test, data);
predict(dM, newdata=data)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
model.matrix(~ subject + weight + sex:test - 1, data)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Works like a charm. How do we know which library to use? R has a huge collection. What is a good reference for these kind of data manipulations?

Comment: @Bee, in this case (and in many others), as you can see, there is no need for any additional library. In general, after some practice, you will see that there is _only_ like a dozen or two of libraries to keep in mind, like `data.table`, `reshape2`, `dplyr`, `ggplot2`, etc., while for more specific tasks you will need to do some searching. The best way to learn is by practicing and StackOverflow is a great place for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think `model.matrix` is most natural here (see @Julius' answer), but here's an alternative:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

dcast(data, subject+weight~test+sex, fun=length, drop=c(TRUE,FALSE))


   subject weight cond1_F cond1_M cond2_F cond2_M control_F control_M
1:       1      2       0       0       0       0         0         1
2:       2      3       1       0       0       0         0         0
3:       3      2       0       0       1       0         0         0
4:       4      4       0       0       0       0         0         1
5:       5      3       0       0       0       0         1         0
6:       6      2       0       0       0       0         1         0
```

To get the columns in the "right" order (with the control first), set factor levels before casting:

```
data[, test := relevel(test, "control")]
dcast(data, subject+weight~test+sex, fun=length, drop=c(TRUE,FALSE))


   subject weight control_F control_M cond1_F cond1_M cond2_F cond2_M
1:       1      2         0         1       0       0       0       0
2:       2      3         0         0       1       0       0       0
3:       3      2         0         0       0       0       1       0
4:       4      4         0         1       0       0       0       0
5:       5      3         1         0       0       0       0       0
6:       6      2         1         0       0       0       0       0
```

(Note: reshape2's dcast isn't so good here, since its `drop` option applies to both rows and cols.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and detailed explanation. This works too. Any ideas on when to use this method against model.matrix?

Comment: I would only use this way if already coding with the data.table package for a project. It's not worth it to load an extra package just for this task, especially when `model.matrix` does it just as well.  I would do it this way, though, since I find data.table essential and have not really learned many base R commands (`model.matrix`, `reshape`, etc.).